# Store + display text in the abstract environment

Tags: auxiliary-files, filecontents

I am trying to store the text from the abstract environment to a file + display this text as well.
I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \textbf{\textsf{Abstract.}}%
  \filecontents[nosearch,noheader,overwrite]{\jobname.abstract}%
}%
{%
  \endfilecontents%
  \input{\jobname.abstract}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
This is a test abstract.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

However, this results in

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect
```

When I comment out the "\input{\jobname.abstract}" it compiles.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timing issue. Use `\AddToHook`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewCommandCopy{\originalabstract}{\abstract}
\NewCommandCopy{\endoriginalabstract}{\endabstract}

\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \filecontents[nosearch,noheader,overwrite]{\jobname.abstract}%
}%
{%
  \endfilecontents
}
\AddToHook{env/abstract/after}{%
  \begin{originalabstract}\input{\jobname.abstract}\end{originalabstract}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
This is a test abstract.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

I copied the original `abstract` environment, but you're free to use a different formatting.

Comment: Thanks this works! I wasn't aware of the `\AddToHook`.

Comment: This does not seem to work when there is no newline after \begin{abstract}, for example try "\begin{abstract}No newline"

Comment: @jwbos That’s a limitation of filecontents