# Preserving newlines and spaces while writing argument to a file

Tags: catcodes, write

I am making a function that should write its argument to a file (for further processing by Python)

From the following question I get something that mostly works.
[Adding newlines while writing text to a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152472/adding-newlines-while-writing-text-to-a-file)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newwrite\file
\def\mycommand{\begingroup\obeylines\mycommandaux}
\begingroup\obeylines
\gdef\mycommandaux#1{%
  \obeylines%
  \def^^M{^^J}%
  \immediate\openout\file=foobar.tex%
  \immediate\write\file{#1}%
  \immediate\closeout\file%
  \endgroup%
}
\endgroup

\mycommand{1
 leading space
multiple  spaces}

(some text so a pdf is generated)

\end{document}
```

However, lines with leading spaces or double spaces are not preserved, as `foobar.tex` looks as follows:

```
1
leading space
multiple spaces
```

How can I define/modify the command such that it writes the argument to the file with both newlines and multiple spaces preserved?

Comment: you need `\obeyspaces` or use the standard `filecontents` environment which does this already

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Amazing, `\obeyspaces` works! Do you want to post an official answer? Regarding using `filecontents` it is not obvious to me how I could use that with a function argument.

Comment: use it as an environment:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `\obeyspaces` or use the standard `filecontents` environment which does this already.

Comment: Note to others: I ended up using filecontents, and modifying it similar to how it's done here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686815/store-display-text-in-the-abstract-environment